# A weird char at the end of the HTTP response string

Tags: node.js, rest, http, response

I am using below nodejs package to generate some simple restful APIs.

https://github.com/restify/node-restify

But I got a strange char at the end of the response json.

[image]

The server side code is the same as the above link provides.

How am I able to remove the %?

Comment: That's not part of response from code. It's your `zsh` shell. Try running the same file from `bash` shell and you won't find that extra character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zsh` adds a `%` sign to show that it was a partial line and no end-of-line delimiter was encountered. [More here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol)

CURL requests reply JSONs, without any EOL delimiter, hence `%` sign. Run the same command from `bash` shell and no such behaviour will be seen.

PS: [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is really good tool to test APIs

Comment: But why when I do "curl https://api.github.com ", it didn't have the % sign at the end of the return json?